# How to iterate over strings in pandas dataframe and remove unwanted words?

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, string, dataframe

I'm trying to clean up a Pandas dataframe called **names2**. It consists of 599,864 rows,  549,317 of them are non-null. In each row under the column in question, `'primary_profession'` there is either 1 string, an array of strings or NaN.

Here is a look at how I loaded the dataframe:

```
name_basics_imdb = pd.read_csv('imdb.name.basics.csv.gz')
names = name_basics_imdb
names2 = names.copy(deep=True)
```

(Note: I dropped some columns and rows and renamed a column, if you need more details they'll gladly be supplied)

Here is a view of names2.info( )

```
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 599865 entries, 0 to 599864
Data columns (total 4 columns):
 #   Column              Non-Null Count   Dtype 
---  ------              --------------   ----- 
 0   nconst              599865 non-null  object
 1   primary_name        599865 non-null  object
 2   primary_profession  549317 non-null  object
 3   known_for_titles    569766 non-null  object
dtypes: object(4)
memory usage: 18.3+ MB
```

names2.head( )

```py
    nconst       primary_name                  primary_profession                         known_for_titles
0   nm0061671   Mary Ellen Bauder   miscellaneous,production_manager,producer   tt0837562,tt2398241,tt0844471,tt0118553
1   nm0061865   Joseph Bauer       composer,music_department,sound_department   tt0896534,tt6791238,tt0287072,tt1682940
2   nm0062070   Bruce Baum                miscellaneous,actor,writer            tt0363631
3   nm0062195   Axel Baumann    camera_department,cinematographer,art_department    tt0114371,tt2004304,tt1618448,tt1224387
4   nm0062798   Pete Baxter production_designer,art_department,set_decorator    tt0452644,tt0452692,tt34580
```

The goal is to iterate through each row's string, strings, or Nan and just keep the rows with *writer, writer director, or just director*. Any other profession can be thrown out. For instance, in row 2: *miscellaneous, actor, writer* are in the `primary_profession` column, *miscellaneous* and *actor* can be eliminated leaving only *writer* in that row.

Any rows where there is no *writer* or *director* or contain NaN can be dropped.

Here are a few of the attempts I made

```
#inverse filtering

value_list = ['miscellaneous', 'production_manager', 'composer', 'music_department', 'sound_department',
      'miscellaneous', 'actor', '...', 'costume_department', 'costume_designer', 'actress', 'art_director', 'music_department' ]

#have to split the arrays first

inverse_bool_series = ~names2.primary_profession.isin(value_list)
names2_filtered = names2[inverse_bool_series]
names2_filtered
```

I also tried

```
names2['primary_profession'] = names2['primary_profession'].str.split(",").str[:3]
names2['primary_profession']
(names2['primary_profession'][0])
type(names2['primary_profession'][0][0])
```

And then there was this

```
for index, row in names2.iterrows():
    idx = list(len(range(names2.primary_profession)))
    for i in idx:
        print(row['primary_profession'][i])
```

To summarize, the goal is for the dataframe `names2` to have only rows with the profession **writer, writer director, or just writer**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
In [96]: names2
Out[96]:
      nconst       primary_name                                         primary_profession                         known_for_titles
0  nm0061671  Mary Ellen Bauder  miscellaneous,production_manager,producer,director,writer  tt0837562,tt2398241,tt0844471,tt0118553
1  nm0061865       Joseph Bauer                 composer,music_department,sound_department  tt0896534,tt6791238,tt0287072,tt1682940
2  nm0062070         Bruce Baum                                 miscellaneous,actor,writer                                tt0363631
3  nm0062195       Axel Baumann           camera_department,cinematographer,art_department  tt0114371,tt2004304,tt1618448,tt1224387
4  nm0062798        Pete Baxter           production_designer,art_department,set_decorator              tt0452644,tt0452692,tt34580

In [97]: profs = names2['primary_profession'].str.split(',').explode()

In [98]: profs
Out[98]:
0          miscellaneous
0     production_manager
0               producer
0               director
0                 writer
1               composer
1       music_department
1       sound_department
2          miscellaneous
2                  actor
2                 writer
3      camera_department
3        cinematographer
3         art_department
4    production_designer
4         art_department
4          set_decorator
Name: primary_profession, dtype: object

In [99]: filtered_profs = profs[profs.isin(['writer', 'writer director', 'director'])]

In [100]: filtered_profs.groupby(filtered_profs.index).agg(','.join)
Out[100]:
0    director,writer
2             writer
Name: primary_profession, dtype: object

In [101]: names2.drop('primary_profession', axis=1).join(filtered_profs.groupby(filtered_profs.index).agg(','.join), how='inner')
Out[101]:
      nconst       primary_name                         known_for_titles primary_profession
0  nm0061671  Mary Ellen Bauder  tt0837562,tt2398241,tt0844471,tt0118553    director,writer
2  nm0062070         Bruce Baum                                tt0363631             writer
```

Comment: Sir, if I were by you I would shake your hand. Not only does this code work and is laid it out in perfect fashion, but It answers different tiers of questions I had. So you helped a beginner coder progress tonight. Thank you @Asish M.

Answer (score 1):

```
# set the words you want to match.
matched_words = ['writer', 'writer_director', 'director']

#drop rows which has nan in column 'primary_profession'
names2 = names.dropna(axis='index', subset=['primary_profession'])

#extract all matched words
names2_extractall = names2['primary_profession'].str.extractall(rf'({"|".join(matched_words)})')

#groupby index and join those matches result by ','
mod_prof = names2_extractall.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: ",".join(x.iloc[:, 0]))

#assign to column 'primary_profession'
names2 = names2.assign(primary_profession=mod_prof)

#drop no matched rows
names2 = names2.dropna(axis='index', subset=['primary_profession'])
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. I tried your code above, and it cleaned up the primary_profession column really well. It did have some NaNs under the modified_profession column, though and only writer no director. Again, the reason why is beyond me.

Comment: I don't know exactly which words you need to match (`matched_words = ['??','xx',...]`), revise it for your need. and I should remove NaNs again depend on `modified_profession`, Thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: It's hard to say. When I ran len(names2.primary_profession.unique()) it returned 8627. So instead of sifting through all of those values, I'd try  the answer from Ashish M.

Comment: Let me know if there's a step I'm missing though.

Comment: @NateBates I think it just an assignment problem with naming? I updated code to assign `primary_profession` directly and revised `matched_words` I guessed.

Comment: Okay, I ran it and it outputs the correct professions. Nicely done. One thing is, and you might want to try this on your own machine, but it seemed to run a lot slower than @Ashish M.'s answer. Let me know if you find the same thing. And thanks again

Comment: @NateBates yup, slower than Ashish M.'s answer
1.59 ms ± 4.63 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
2.83 ms ± 44.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233977/discussion-between-natebates-and-scku).

Answer (score 0):

```
unwanted_row_indices=[]
for index,row in names2.iterrows():
    if('writer' in row['primary_profession'].lower()):
        pass
    else:
        unwanted_row_indices.append(index)
names2=names2.drop(unwanted_row_indices,axis=0)
```

Comment: loop might not be an efficient way, especially if it is a large df

Comment: Thanks for reaching out. I tried the code and it threw this error `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'contains'` Not sure if I did something wrong

Comment: Thank you so much for raising a concern. My bad, I have made the correction in the if statement. Please make the change and let me know if this works out.

Comment: As far as solving the problem of cleaning the data, you succeeded. However, I'm going to have to agree with @Ade_1, after some investigating, that a loop isn't the most efficient way to solve this problem in Pandas. https://towardsdatascience.com/you-dont-always-have-to-loop-through-rows-in-pandas-22a970b347ac check out this article I found which can explain it way better than I can. Thanks again for answering.